# offsetLeft Javascript property takes more time

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**offsetLeft** Javascript property takes more time.

offLeft = $('div')[0].offsetLeft

while check with profiling in chrome, i have found this offsetLeft takes more time while running my code. Any suggestions for replacing offsetLeft property?

```
function firstcol() {
        var sheet = this.getSheet(), left, right, leftIdx, rightIdx, hScroll = this._hScroller(sheetIdx), colWtColl = sheet._colWidthCollection,
            hhandle = hScroll.element.find(".e-hhandle"), hsLeft = parseInt(**hhandle[0].offsetLeft**);
        left = hsLeft * hScroll._scrollData.onePx;
        right = (hsLeft + hhandle[0].offsetWidth) * hScroll._scrollData.onePx;
        leftIdx = this._sortProcess(colWtColl, left);
        sheet._leftCol = { idx: leftIdx, value: colWtColl[leftIdx] };
        rightIdx = this._sortProcess(colWtColl, right);
        sheet._rightCol = { idx: rightIdx, value: colWtColl[rightIdx] };
    }
```

In this block of code takes 1500ms to run., offsetLft takes 1100 ms. how can i reduce this. Avg run time for this 350 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset* properties require the page flow to be up-to-date. If you've previously made a change to the DOM or styling that's invalidated the currently computed flow, then getting offsetLeft will cause the browser to reflow the page. It's the reflow that takes the time. If you haven't made such a previous change, then offsetLeft can use the current page flow and is fast.

So the problem is not offsetLeft per se, but the JS that precedes it since the last page reflow.